# AzureAD user roles for Intune

Tags: entra-id, microsoft-intune

Having trouble assigning user permissions in AzureAD. I have a *Limited administrator*  with ALL roles selected [including *Intune Service administrator*]. When I get into the portal I get **Experiencing authentication issues** notifications for:

> The portal is having issues getting authentication tokens for Microsoft_Intune_DeviceSettings.
>
> The portal is having issues getting authentication tokens for fx.

I am unable to manage Intune settings. When I log in as account owner, there is no such problem.

What role/permission am I missing?

Comment: What do you try to achieve ?  Which portal did you get into?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT. I experience the issue in the Azure Portal. An important piece I should add is that my Limited Admin user has Conditional Access configured in Intune for all apps except everything that has to do with Azure. When condition is satisfied, there is no issue. When not satisfied I get the authentication issues. But ALL Azure related apps I could find are excluded from the policy.